# dotnet core and angular node dependency?

Tags: angular, .net-core

Having a hard time trying to figure out why my dotnet new angular application has a node dependency when running through iis?  Using Visual Studio Code and dotnet core 1.0.4, after publishing, my application still has a dependency on node.js?  Not sure why.  We are running the application through iis, but our production server does not have node installed and this results in a 500 status code.  We are using Microsoft spa package which has angular 2.

Has anyone else had any similar issue?

How can I remove the node dependency?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates for this.  If so, you have two options to create a production build:

1. Use the command `dotnet publish -c Release`
2. Use the publish option under the build menu in Visual Studio 2017

A good tutorial and walkthrough can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/)

Comment: so by using option 1, then there will be no node dependency?

Comment: Correct, once you do a production build, any web server capable of serving static files should be able to host your application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy the build.

you can get the build static content through.

```
 ng build --prod --aot
```

It will create a dist folder deploy that code.